# What is the scope of Metaplex's Candy Machine

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

It seems like [Metaplex's candy-machine](https://docs.metaplex.com/overviews/candy_machine_overview) ships with some built-in assumptions about the way tokens will be minted and sold. Such as:

1. All NFTs in the collection will have the same price.
2. Buyers cannot pick WHICH asset in the collection they want to buy; what you get is a surprise.

Is this correct? Or is it more flexible?

I'm curious if candy-machine handle either of the following circumstances:

A. a small collection of unique tokens that buyers can choose specifically? Not randomly assigned?

B. 10 "copies" of the same original. [Metaplex framework documentation](https://docs.metaplex.com/about/terminology) calls these Prints and Master Edition, respectively. It's unclear to me how these concepts relate to a candy_machine sale (if at all).

Are uses-cases like these simply out of scope for Candy Machine?

Answer (score 0):

Candy Machine is a tool that works as same as it sounds like a Candy Machine it allows you to fill it up with mint data(like price, date, images, whitelist) and then it allows the user to mint NFTs. According to the given scope of work you have described you can use the token-metadata program which you are indirectly using when you are using the candy machine. Candy machines uses the token-metadata program under the hood to mint NFTs. So if you want to do any fancy stuff you can use the token-metadata program to build out something of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Candy machine distributes all tokens in random order, there is no option for the user to select the minted token, that's to prevent sniping of the rare NFTs as links to all metadata files are available on chain.

If you want to allow users to mint specific NFTs, you can use the Metpalex JS SDK and create an offchain version of the required functionality - check `create` and `updateMetadata` in https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-next

The only option for variable prices with Candy Machine is:

- use end mint settings to stop the mint after a specified date or number of mints and the manually change the price
- distribute whitelist tokens that will allow minting at discounted price

You can't use prints with candy machine, but you can check the hidden settings in Candy Machine docs, which allow you adding a single URI that will be used for all mints.

Some of the mentioned options are covered here: https://hackmd.io/@halaprix/S1W4vc9CY